# stop embeddable Tomcat from java code

Tags: java, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-8

This might be a newbie question, but still, I need help!!

I have a java class that succesfully starts embeddable Tomcat like this:

```
    public class Main {

    private static Tomcat tomcat;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String webappDirLocation = "webapps/";
        tomcat = new Tomcat();

        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8080";
        }

        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));
        StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

My question is, ¿how can I stop it?

I tried to add another function for this purpose like this:

```
    public static void stopTomcat() throws Exception {

    if (tomcat.getServer() != null) {
        tomcat.stop();
        tomcat.destroy();
    }
}
```

calling it from the main method like this:

```
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("stopTomcat")) {
             stopTomcat();
             return;
        }
```

However, it doesn't work. I'm getting a thread exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

How can I get the current Tomcat server's variable that is running in order to stop tomcat?

I just need to be able to run a java class from command line in order to stop Tomcat, and I believe it is posible. Using catalina.bat, or Tomcat.exe is out of the question since this is an embeddable version of tomcat.

Any help will be really really appreciated!!

Regards!!

Comment: a quick question to you, in which jar did you get Tomcat.java file  ? is it something which you created ?

Comment: there is a Tomcat.class (package: org.apache.catalina.startup) in tomcat-embed-core.jar

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running your script twice. Once starting the server and another time stopping it.

If you run it only once, you still have the reference to the Tomcat object, and thus can call stop on it.
If not, it will be null, or will be a different instance altogether.

The code below, briefly shows how to stop Tomcat from the same script.

```
    String webappDirLocation = "webapps/";
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

    Runnable task2 = () -> {  try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Stopping Tomcat");
        tomcat.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } };

    // start the thread
    new Thread(task2).start();

    String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if (webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8080";
    }

    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));
    tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
```

Apart from a timer, you could also stop the server when pressing a key:

```
    ... 
    tomcat.start();
    //      tomcat.getServer().await();

    System.out.print("Press key to stop ");     
    if(System.in.read()!=-1) {
        System.out.print("Stopping");
        tomcat.stop();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however, how can I invoke that "task2" from command line?and yes, you're right about me using a different instance.

Comment: also, would that task2 won't stop tomcat when it's supposed to start?

Comment: the example above shows that if you have the same Tomcat instance object then you can act on it, and so stop it. Yes the program will stop altogether after 5 seconds.

Comment: if you use a different JVM instance, then maybe a standard tomcat is ok no ?

Comment: but how do I call that "task2" that stops Tomcat? right now I run this class from command line like this:

java -cp "some_classpath" Main

what should I do when I need to stop it?

Comment: you can remove task2, and wait for a key input to stop the server ...I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's one workaround, however, I was hoping to be able to stop it by running some java code, I mean, ultimately, I want the user to be able to stop it by clicking a button on the browser (which may run some java class or something) or by executing some .bat file, instead of having to type "ctrl-c", so it's stopped gracefully.

Comment: its not a workaround. The server is stopped gracefully because the stop method is called properly on the same tomcat instance, not killing the process from a shell like with Ctrl-C.